# Saving a list containing a numpy array in CSV format in Python

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I am trying to save a list `sigma1` containing a numpy array in `CSV` format. In the current output, the data is saved in multiple rows without commas. In the expected output, I want the data to be saved in a single row with commas, exactly like `sigma1`.

```
import numpy as np
import csv

sigma1= [np.array([[0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109],
       [0.02109]])]


with open('Data_sigma.csv', 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     print(sigma1)
     f.writelines('sigma'+ '\n')
     f.write(str(sigma1))
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Comment: If you write out the NumPy array to your CSV file the expected output will simply contain each value separated by a comma (no `np.array`) i.e. `[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109],[0.02109]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using the file to write your lines rather than the csv writer.  Use the csv writer with the `writerow` function to write a single row to the CSV file:

```
with open('Data_sigma.csv', 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerow(sigma1[0])
```

Note, as sigma1 is a list containing the NumPy array, we have written out `sigma1[0]`.  If you have multiple NumPy arrays in sigma1 then you can write all of these out to your file using `writerows` as follows:

```
with open('Data_sigma.csv', 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(sigma1)
```